# How does git manage to track changes if the complete folder structure is changed?

Tags: git

I am working on branch and I recently refactored my folder structure, lot of files were moved here and there, many were renamed as well. But when I merged master(old structure) to my current branch git was able to understand where the files are and automatically merged the code without conflicts. How is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two parts to this "how", which can be summarized this way:

- For *committing*, Git doesn't *care*.  It just makes snapshots.  Whatever file names you told Git to use to hold whatever file contents you told Git to use—all of which are stored in your index at the time you run `git commit`, which is why you have to `git add` files all the time, to copy them over the old versions in the index—Git just freezes *all* of those files, with whatever they have in the index *right now*, when you run `git commit`.  Those frozen files are the snapshot for the commit.

  In other words, after you rearrange everything with `git mv` (which changes the names in the index and work-tree both), and update the contents with `git add` as needed, and then `git commit`, you get a new snapshot with the new names and any updated contents.  The old snapshots remain exactly as they were: all existing snapshots are frozen forever, or at least, for as long as the commit itself lives.  (The default is for them to live forever.  It's possible to *remove* commits, but this is only easy-ish until you spread them to other repositories, after which they will keep re-infecting your repository from the other repositories even if you delete them from your own.)
- For *comparing*—which includes merging—Git has to discover / detect renamed files.  Git does this by comparing the files' *content*.

The claim in the second bullet point here is actually a bit of an exaggeration, but let's see how it works by illustrating with `git diff`, which—at least in the mode we care about here—compares two commits.  Remember that each commit represents a complete snapshot of all files.  We'll find the two commits' hash IDs, and run:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash of earlier commit> <hash of later commit>
```

What Git will do at this point is extract each of the two commits.  (The "extracting" gets short circuited as much as possible, which is usually a lot: Git can usually examine the frozen commits directly in place.  But that's just a speed optimization; you can think of this as Git completely extracting both commits into a temporary work area.)  Let's call the earlier commit *old* and the later one *new* here.<sup>1</sup>  The job of `git diff` is to tell you *what to do to change old to new*.  This isn't necessarily what any human who did the changing did, just some set of instructions that will *produce the the same result*.

To find these instructions, Git will:

- First, find all the files that have exactly the same name in *old* and *new*.  Git assumes that if *old* has a file named `README` and *new* has a file named `README`, these must be "the same" file.  These files are paired-up: they're now taken out of the equation, for the moment.  Git hasn't yet figured out what to do to *change* the paired-up files, it's just paired them up.
- (There's a step you can insert here using the `-B` option, to commands that have one.  But we'll ignore it for now, as it just makes this complicated.)
- Now, if there are *unpaired* files, these represent files that went missing from *old* and/or showed up out of the blue in *new* ... or do they?  Maybe they are files that were *renamed*, that had some name O in *old* and some different name N in *new*.  Here, Git computes a *similarity index* number for each possible pairing of files.

  For speed purposes, Git can very quickly pair up any two files (one from *old*, one from *new*) that are 100% identical.  That usually greatly shrinks the pool of files that have to be compared the hard way.

  Finally, Git is down to unpaired files that it should consider pairing up even though they're not 100%, bit-for-bit identical.  Git now does the full similarity index computation (using the same [xdelta-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdelta) code that Git uses for doing delta compression in pack files) on every pair of files.  (This requires really extracting all these files' data.)  Whichever files get the *best* pairing score are paired together, if the scores exceed the minimum you chose, which defaults to "50% similar".
- Files that remain unpaired after all of this extra work are either just deleted or created anew.  (There are a few more complications introduced here if you add `--find-copies` or `--find-copies-harder`, but again, we'll ignore them here.)

Now that the files have been paired-up—i.e., now that `git diff` knows that, say, file `README.md` in *old* mostly matches file `README.rst` in *new*, so that these two files must really be one single file, with one identity, rather than two different files with two identities—*now* Git compares each paired-up file to produce instructions:

- `-`: delete this line from the version of the file found in *old*
- `+`: add this line to the version of the file found in *old*

If you follow all the instructions, including any "rename this file" instruction given at the top, that will change the file found in *old* to the one found in *new*.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can, if you like, reverse the hash IDs.  Then Git will tell you how to turn the newer commit into the older commit.

---

#### How `git merge` uses `git diff`

When merging two commits, Git uses the *commit graph*—the Directed Acyclic Graph formed by looking at each commit's parent hash or hashes to connect all the individual commits into one big DAG—to find the best common ancestor commit.  This commit is the *merge base* of the two specified commits.

The `git merge` command then, in effect, runs *two* `git diff` commands.  Both have `--find-renames` enabled, with the similarity threshold defaulting to 50%. You can use `-X find-renames=<number>` to alter this threshold, to allow more or fewer pairings of files whose names did not match.

The two diffs are:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash of merge base> <hash of HEAD commit>
```

and:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash of merge base> <hash of other commit>
```

Both diffs do the similarity computations as needed on any unpaired file names during the internal `git diff`.

#### The complications

Adding `-B` tells Git to *break* automatically-paired files: just because a file is named `README` in both commits doesn't mean that this is really *the same* file.  What if, for instance, you renamed `README` to `old/README`, then renamed `new/README` to `README`?  In this case, Git will do a similarity computation on the automatically-paired files in that step I noted earlier.  If the similarity is too *low*, Git will break the pairing.  Later, if the similarity is not too *extremely* low, and the pairing remains broken, Git will rejoin the two files, so `-B` takes *two* numbers, not just one.

The merge command does not allow you to supply a `-B` argument.  (Arguably, it should.)

If you use `--find-copies` or `--find-copies-harder`, Git will look at some or all of the source ("old") files to see if a newly-created destination ("new") file was copied from it.  These use the same similarity index.  This step happens after rename detection, and will sometimes only consider modified files as possible sources, again because it's expensive computationally.

The merge command does not allow you to specify the find-copies options either.